# CentOS 6.2 disable httpd autoindex

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, directoryindex

I am trying to disable the Auto index of directories in the apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.co.uk www.example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.com/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
    Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

Will putting `Options -Indexes` into the VirtualHost configuration disable autoindex in these directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by putting in `Options -Indexes` you disable autoindex for the entire VirtualHost.

You can read about it in the [Apache Core Features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) documentation if you would like to learn more about it.